# Accessing public methods in private inner classes

Tags: java, methods, inner-classes, private-methods

I have the following code, I wanted to know how to access the `public method:locationFinder` in the `private inner class:LocationBasedFormatter` of the `outer class:LocationFormatter`.

Basically I would like to access the method `locationFinder` from `MyClass` and get the `List<String>`

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class LocationFormatter {

    public static final Formatter Location(String longitute, String latitude) {
        return new LocationBasedFormatter(longitute, latitude)
    }

    public static interface Formatter {}

    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static final class LocationBasedFormatter implements Formatter {
        private String longitute;
        private String latitude;

        public final List < String > locationFinder() {
            String location = "Your Long: " + this.longitute + " Your Lat: " + this.latitude;
            List < String > randomList = new ArrayList < String > ()
            randomList.add(location)
            return randomList;
        }

    }
}
```

Following is my other main class from where I need to pass the value and access the `locationFinder`  method:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        LocationFormatter loc = new LocationFormatter();
        LocationBasedFormatter result = loc.Location("44.54", "94.54");
    }
}
```

When I try to find the Objects/Methods on `loc` or `result` then I am unable to find my Method `locationFinder`. I would like to access `locationFinder` method and get the `List` based on the values I passed to my private variable.

I am a bit confused and unable to get the method in another class. However, if I write the main method within the same class then I am able to access it.

Comment: @maloomeister Thanks for your response. Basically I want to access the `locationFinder` method from `MyClass` by passing the values. Do you mean `LocationBasedFormatter result = loc.Location("44.54","94.54");`?

Comment: If you need to access `locationFinder` method, maybe you should have declared it in interface `Formatter`?

Comment: @AlexRudenko Yes you are correct, I tried that, and it's working. Just out of curiosity what if I do not want to add the `Method` in `Interface`? How can I access it then. Because in another class I have methods which take different parameter as input and produce different output so I cannot add method in `Interface` in those cases how can I access method and get result without add the Method in interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to declare method `locationFinder` in interface `Formatter` and use this interface (which is currently just a marker interface) instead of its specific implementation in private class:

```java
public static interface Formatter {
    List<String> locationFinder();
}
```

Then this method will be accessible publicly:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // no need to instantiate LocationFormatter, Location is static method
        Formatter result = LocationFormatter.Location("44.54", "94.54");

        List<String> locationList = result.locationFinder();
    }
}
```

However, more descriptive names should be used for classes and methods in this code.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I tried that, and it's working. Just out of curiosity what if I do not want to add the Method in Interface? How can I access it then. Because in another class I have methods which take different parameter as input and produce different output so I cannot add method in Interface in those cases how can I access method and get result without add the Method in interface

Comment: If you need to allow access to other methods of the private nested class than defined in the contract/interface, possibly this class should not be private and nested at all?  It's up to you how you design your class and interface structure :)

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your answer and clarification.
Have a great day ahead :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically `LocationBasedFormatter` is not an inner class. It's a [static nested class.](https://github.com/razib-playground/stepover/blob/master/languages/java8/src/nestedclass/nested-class.md)

Add a `public static getLocationBasedFormatterInstance()` method in the `LocationFormatter` class. This `getLocationBasedFormatterInstance()` could return the instance of `LocationBaedFomratter`

```
public class LocationFormatter {
  ... 
  public static getLocationBasedFormatterInstance(){
     LocationBasedFormatter lbf = new LocationBasedFormatter();
     return lbf;

  }

}
```

Then you have to create an object of your static nested class `LocationBasedFormatter` from your main method.

```
LocationFormatter.LocationBasedFormatter locationFormatter = new LocationFormatter();
LocationBaedFomratter loationBasedFomratter = locationFormatter.getLocationBasedFormatterInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am unable to create the object based on `LocationFormatter.LocationBasedFormatter` as my `LocationBasedFormatter` is private. It throws me the error `The type LocationFormatter.LocationBasedFormatter is not visible`. Is there any other way to do it by keeping the `static nested class` private?